# Email function not carrying out correctly

Tags: php, html

Ok so ive worked on this for an hour or so and I've just gone blind to what the issue is. Can someone point out what I need to change to make the below code setup so that email address entered in the form sends an email to my admin email account on my server, lets call it admin@email.com. Below is the html forma nd the php code.
PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "admin@email.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be  valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
    <table width="450px">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6">  </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a   href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Also just to add the above form completes successfully and on my server email account I get no email, not even to report email not sent and also no email in the proposed recipient in case I had it backwards.

Comment: which e-mail provider do you use to send your emails?

Comment: squirrel  I think but I didnt set up a e-mail provider I just used the defualt set up on cPanel. A test email was successful to the recipient address previously so the email server is working

Comment: Ok thank you for your input, from the code though can you see any reason it would be not sending?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any email provider or third party software ON A WORKING SERVER.
I tested the code and it works without problem on server (but shouldn't work on local machine). Do you work locally or on a server? Here's a note from PHP site:

> The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the
>   Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for
>   composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a
>   MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the
>   localhost or a remote machine). Second, the custom headers like From:,
>   Cc:, Bcc: and Date: are not interpreted by the MTA in the first place,
>   but are parsed by PHP. As such, the to parameter should not be an
>   address in the form of "Something ". The mail
>   command may not parse this properly while talking with the MTA.

More information: [PHP: mail - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: referenced the admin email instead of the user email and so was not seeing the email. i'm hosted on a server not locally.

Answer (score 0):

OK so after awhile I figured out that i was referencing the wrong email. I was logged into my admin email account on my server and not the user account i created so was not seeing the emails. Stupid enough reason, but working now none the less. Thanks for your help.